# ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql

why i'm always getting an error like this when I'm trying to INNER JOIN tbl_interview_schedule to tbl_reservation_info_id?

```
SELECT CI.*, HM.*, TP.*, RI.*, IS.*
FROM tbl_client_info AS CI

INNER JOIN tbl_reservation_info AS RI
ON RI.client_info_id = CI.client_info_id

INNER JOIN tbl_house_model AS HM
ON HM.house_model_id = RI.house_model_id

INNER JOIN tbl_type_of_payment AS TP
ON TP.type_of_payment_id = RI.type_of_payment_id

INNER JOIN tbl_interview_schedule AS IS
ON IS.reservation_info_id = RI.reservation_info_id

WHERE RI.reservationstatus = 'For Interview' AND TP.paymenttype = 'Cash'
```

Comment: Include the error message in the body of the post ...

Comment: Is `IS` a keyword that you're not escaping?

Comment: `AS IS` - the IS is a reserved word. Try aliasing to something else.

Comment: thanks for downvoting ... if the <name it> can't post ...

Answer (score 5):

`IS` is a reserved word in MySQL.